# Keras backend function equivalent for str.format

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, tensorflow

How to perform the following function using Keras backend?

```
"{0:b}".format(37)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please consider expanding your question to include more details about what you are trying to achieve. It is not clear why you want to do a string formatting operation in Keras.

Comment: I was actually trying to apply integer operations on the tensor objects by casting them using K.cast(x, dtype= tf.int32).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need that? You shouldn't need to do anything like that using the backend, as Keras will take strings as arguments, or you can use a regular print function.

There are certain special formatting options in Keras, for example, saving model weights during training, inserting the current epoch and validation loss into the name to help give them meaning. This is shown in the documentation for [the ModelCheckpoint callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint)

If you really want to do something special, the Tensorflow backend does have a [`tf.Print` function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print). I am not sure if you can call this directly from `keras.backend.Print` or whether you need to directly use tensorflow, with `tf.Print` - either way it would be the same operation being performed.

Comment: I'm actually trying to apply integer operations on the tensor objects in an intermediate labda layer function in keras using the keras backend.

Comment: @cuser - so why are you asking about a `print` function?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I was actually trying to apply integer operations on the tensor objects by casting them using K.cast(x, dtype= tf.int32).